# Audit mail send

Tags: vba, email, insert, call

I have the email script below. How do I include a call to insert, for each record, the activity date (Date email sent) along with fields [EmailAddress],[Due Date] into an audit table (tblauditlist)?

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim rsEmails As DAO.Recordset

    Const sBODY As String = "Test Email - Delete Me"
    Const sSUBJ As String = "Mailing List Test"
    Const sSQL As String = "SELECT [EmailAddress],[Due Date] &""   ""&[EvalFor] As Subjj FROM tblMailingList;"

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set rsEmails = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

    'Create them, but don't send yet
    Do Until rsEmails.EOF
        Set olMailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        With olMailItem
            .To = rsEmails.Fields("EmailAddress").Value
            .Subject = rsEmails.Fields("Subjj").Value
            .Body = sBODY
            .Save
        End With
        rsEmails.MoveNext

        olMailItem.Send
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If it can be reasonably assumed that your [tblAuditList] has three text based field ([eml],[errno],[errdsc]) and a datetime that defaults to Now() then these additions should be sufficient.

```
Const sQRY String = "INSERT INTO tblAuditList ([eml],[errno],[errdsc]) VALUES ('×E×','×S×','×D×');"   'put this above with the others

    'all of the regular code above this
    olMailItem.Send
    CurrentDb.Execute Replace(Replace(Replace(sQRY, "×E×", CStr(rsEmails.Fields("EmailAddress"))), _
                                                    "×S×", Err.Number), _
                                                    "×D×", IIf(Err.Number, Err.Description, "Success")), _
                      dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges
Loop
```

If you prefer to keep the Err.Number as true numbers, change the [tblAuditList].[errno] to be of type Number and remove the quotes wrapping the insert values. For logs like this, I always prefer to let a default Now() populate a datetime field as the events are usually being written realtime.

Note that those are Chr(215) 'times' characters and not regular lower-case x's.

Answer (score 0):

Add a VBA append query using the DAO database connection inside the loop:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim db As DAO.Database              ' ADDED DECLARATION
    Dim rsEmails As DAO.Recordset

    Const sBODY As String = "Test Email - Delete Me"
    Const sSUBJ As String = "Mailing List Test"
    Const sSQL As String = "SELECT [EmailAddress],[Due Date] &""   ""&[EvalFor] As Subjj FROM tblMailingList;"

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsEmails = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)    ' CHANGED INITIALIZATION

    'Create them, but don't send yet
    Do Until rsEmails.EOF
        Set olMailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        With olMailItem
            .To = rsEmails.Fields("EmailAddress").Value
            .Subject = rsEmails.Fields("Subjj").Value
            .Body = sBODY
            .Save
        End With

        olMailItem.Send        

        ' APPEND QUERY
        db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblAuditList ([DateEmailSent], [EmailAddress], [Due Date]) " _
                & " VALUES (#" & Date & "#, '" & rsEmails!EmailAddress & "', #" & rsEmails![Due Date] & "#), dbFailOnError

        rsEmails.MoveNext
    Loop

    ' CLOSING RECORDSET
    rsEmails.Close

    ' UNINITIALIZING OBJECTS
    Set rsEmails = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The above suggestion from Parfait works well however my audit table only appends the first record. I tried moving things around to no avail. Here is an abbreviated version of what I have:                                     Set rsEmails = db.OpenRecordset("LateMe")
Do Until rsEmails.EOF 
{Email code}
' APPEND QUERY
db.Execute "INSERT INTO AuditList ([DateEmailSent], [Email], [Namee]) " _
& " VALUES (#" & Date & "#, '" & rsEmails!Email & "', '" & rsEmails![Namee] & "');"
             
olMailItem.Send

End With
        
    rsEmails.MoveNext
        
    Loop

Comment: See my edit. Simply move `rsEmails.MoveNext` at end of loop after email and append query. Do note your code here is using a different recordset. Be sure fields are available in `LateMe` table or query.